# What does the shield icon mean after someone's online name?

Tags: forza-horizon

I have seen a shield icon after people's name online but I don't know what it means. I know the crown is VIP because I have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a shield means the user is a member of or owner of a Car Club.

Full shield means owner; shield with line means member.

Answer (score 0):

The full shield means club owner- the shield with a half means your a co owner of the club, like you are higher than members but lower then the owner